# Getting Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors version issue in WebAPI

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, asp.net-web-api, cross-domain

I have installed `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors` package using `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors` in my WebApi project(.net framework 4.5.2) and now I'm getting below error while compiling the project.

Reference: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

> Assembly 'System.Web.Http.Cors, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' uses 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

Comment: What version of Web API is used in project?

Comment: I'm having the same EXACT issue almost a year later, working in VS2015.

Comment: Solution is marked below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to install following nuget package for this.

Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors.ko  -Version 5.0.0

This will work.

Comment: Thanks, I uninstalled the previous one and installed the lower version & it worked well.

Comment: You don't need the .ko (Korean version), `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors` is enough...

Answer (score 0):

make sure your packages are up to date. 
if you update and you still have the same error
- uninstall your packages one by one until you get your system.web.http disappear from the references 
- then add the references again this should fix your build error

Comment: installing version webapi 5.0.0 means going down to a previous version which can cause other problems. there is no need to downgrade to lower version just fix the latest version reference

Comment: @MohanadHaddadin You're right. You'd have to fix the dependency chain accordingly when you downgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, but doing this **"Update-Package –reinstall Microsoft.AspNet.Cors"** fixed my problem

  -