# System.Web.Http reference version reducing from v5.2.3.0 to v5.1.0.0 after installing fluentvalidation.webapi

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, nuget, fluentvalidation

I want to install fluentvalidation.webapi package in my webApi project. When i install this package through nuget, i notice a strange thing that it reduces the version of my system.web.http reference.

System.Web.Http reference version before fluentvalidation.webapi package installation: version 5.2.3.0

System.Web.Http reference version after fluentvalidation.webapi package installation: version 5.1.0.0

Can anyone tell me reason for this? this further gives me other issues like [Getting Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors version issue in WebAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29031973/getting-microsoft-aspnet-webapi-cors-version-issue-in-webapi)

Comment: Well, I went through [FluentValidation on GitHub](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation) with a quick search and actually there is only 1 reference to System.Web.Http which is to include the package and to version 5.2.0.0. In NuGet build files, I could find this though `<dependency id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="[5.1,5.3)" />` Not experienced with NuGet packages but maybe you hit an issue with this. Have you tried changing the reference version afterwards? How does your code behave after it?

Comment: yes i did change the version by updating my system.web.http version. It creates problem with some controllers (controller which have same name in MVC and WebApi project in my solution).

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading System.Web.Http to latest version after installing fluentvalidation.webapi. If the dependant library uses specific version of System.Web.Http library, you can specify binding redirect in your web.config, which would basically instruct the app to use most recent version of the library. For documentation on setting binding redirects, please, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twy1dw1e(v=vs.110).aspx