# Wep Api error while installing Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors in web api2

Tags: c#, nuget, asp.net-web-api2

I am installing following package for CORS access in ASP.Net WebAPI:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors
```

But getting following error:

> Error  5   Assembly 'System.Web.Http.Cors, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' uses 'System.Web.Cors, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, 
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Cors, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

[image]

Answer (score 0):

"You need to install following nuget package for this.

Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors.ko -Version 5.0.0"

[Getting Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors version issue in WebAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29031973/5739840)